# C# disable a checkbox based on run-time textbox user input value

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

I have two textbox to let user input start date and end date. Then I have a checkbox that allow user to check to see some calculations. My question is, how can I disable the checkbox if the duration between start date and end date is shorter than a specific length. I mean, right after user input the start date and end date, he/she would see the checkbox is disabled because the time period length is not long enough.

```
if (productWealth.Count < 3)
    checkBox7.Enabled = false;
```

This is what I have now, if `count < 3`, then checkbox 7 is disabled. Seems like the application only run the count when run click the RUN button, but I want them to see immediate effect.

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? Give us a clue, at least. Also, one line of code isn't enough to know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the event `TextChanged`, so when the user change the value of the `TextBox` you check if its true and enable the `CheckBox`.

```
tboxEndDate.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(tboxEndDate_TextChanged);

void tboxEndDate_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // Calcule the productWealth
   if (productWealth.Count < 3) checkBox7.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Leave()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) event for your start and end date textboxes.  Place your if() statement in there.

Uh that is, if this is WinForms...